# How to instantiate a particular view controller with storyboard in iOS at early stage of loading?

Tags: ios, ios5, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, delay

When using tabs with storyboard in iOS 5, some of them may take quite a long time to initialize when switching to it (for example, a tab containing GLKViewController).

This happens because an amount of work in viewDidLoad method in this controller could be very big.

Is there a way to initialize particular view controller (and call it's viewDidLoad method) defined in the storyboard at early stage - when an application starts? Having done this, the delay should be eliminated.

Comment: Why dont you initialize the GLKViewController in the app delegate and then move it to the view at viewDidLoad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure it's the view controller's instantiation and not the `viewDidLoad` method? The view controllers are probably all created when the storyboard is unpacked, but a view controller tries to delay loading its actual view object as long as possible; `viewDidLoad` isn't called until the `view` property of your `UIViewController` subclass is accessed.

So a way around this could be to manually access the view property:

```
__unused CGRect frame = [[tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:index] view].frame;
```

If the slowdown is, in fact, in the instantiation and the view controller isn't being created until you switch to that tab, then you'll have do force the view controller to be instantiated by accessing it programmatically, like in the above example.

Comment: My bad, that was really the viewDidLoad method. And this works just fine, thank you. Will update my question now.

Comment: My code looks like this now: UIViewController *v = [self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:index]; __unused CGRect frame = v.view.frame;   Controllers don't have the frame property :) Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Calling the frame of the vewcontroller or the .view property will most likely work,
but i dont advice you to mess up with the viewcontroller initializations and view settings

For the following reasons

- changes you make will not be standard, they will be tricks and hacks that will later on get out of hand
- changes that you make will not be carried with you easily to other projects you create

If i faced a problem like this i would create the GLKViewController separately for example in the app delegate and held it there, untill the viewDidLoad gets called in the viewController, then i would move this initilized GLKViewController to the viewController

Comment: Yes, I understand that this is actually a "trick", but it is very handy to design a view in the interface builder, rather than do it by hands. It will lead to a considerable amount of code. Wish there is an official way to call this viewDidLoad method.

Comment: Yes you are probably right, i didnt consider that you needed it to be from interface builder and not from coding, this solution may be a good one, although am still not convinced :)

Comment: Anyway, thank you for your answer, because I agree with you, that doing such tricks generally not a good idea :) But here it works and it works well. If I found the other "official" solution I'll post it.

Comment: Thanks, and i am interested too, to see the official solution :)